# how to append ajax html response in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the below code in a ajax call, the success part is returning HTML, and I set 2 variables that sift through the response for particular HTML, I then take that, and loop through it to append it my dom. But in internet explorer version 8 only, it won't append anything. There are no javascript errors either. I am not sure if it's the loop it self of the way I am getting the results, but any help towards the proper approach to this would be appreciated.

```
success: function(data) {

                  var results = $(data).find('li.post');
                var nextGroup = $(data).find('a.page-next').attr('href');

               if(!nextGroup) {

                    $.each(results, function(index,value) {

                            $('#posts').append(value);

                      });

                      params('end');

                } else {

                    params(nextGroup);

                    $.each(results, function(index,value) {

                            $('#posts').append(value);
                      });  
                }
             }
```